# Files missing on drive after copying from other OS

Tags: windows

I'm running Windows 8.

I have one hard drive with two partitions:

C:- for the OS
D:- for files

I connected a laptop drive with Windows 7 containing two partitions:

C:- for the OS 
D:- for files

After connecting the laptop drive I booted up, disk check ran for a while to check the laptop drive. Windows 7 booted up instead of Windows 8. I copied the files from both of the laptop partitions to my Windows 7 HDD's D: partition. In total I copied around 200GB. After rebooting and disconnecting the drive, disk check ran again and booted to Windows 8. I gave away the drive thinking that I had the files but now I can't find them. 
Partition D: shows that 780GB is used on the drive but if select all the files in the drive and check properties the total size of those files is only 611GB so 170GB worth of space is used but the files don't show up. I've tried running [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to check if I maybe deleted the files, but the files don't show up. I tried giving all of the permissions to my Windows account but that didn't help either.

Comment: *"I gave away the drive"* Just for clarity, which drive? Anyway it looks like you are having permission issues, but you should still be able to see the folders, just not be able to open them. Or you don't even see any of the folders you copied?

Comment: I gave away the laptop drive. I couldn't even see the folders via file explorer/command prompt. As i've mentioned in my answer i got to the files through WinDirStat.

Comment: *"I gave away the laptop drive."* That is not clear, we don't know which is your laptop drive. I expected something like "the drive with Windows 7" or "the drive with Windows 8" so that we can pinpoint exactly which drive. *In any case,* glad you found your files.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used WinDirStat which displayed the folder named as "Found.000". My user account didn't have permissions to open the folder so I went to folder properties and added all the permissions to my account. After that I still couldn't open Found.000 but I could open the subfolders with the files I needed.